# I wanted to coordinate the links but could not, I did not understand where I put the code

Tags: html, css

Hi there is a code that does not work, to format the text, I want to remove the font under the links

The code is : text-decoration:none;

I do not understand, the code does not work, I typed it inside: UL, LI, BODY and DIV (id & class)
I tried everything, but I did not understand!

Comment: _The code is : text-decoration:none;_ This is not the code you should have posted here.... _I typed it inside..._ Post this code!

Comment: can you post  your html css plz

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to type your "code" inside anchor tag selector:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NmpjVy)